# A property of Radon-Nikodym derivatives

Tags: measure-theory

Is the Radon-Nikodym derivative linear in countably infinitely many input measures? That is, if $f_i$ is a Radon-Nikodym derivative of the measure $\nu_i$ w.r.t. $\mu$ for $i $ from $1$ to $ \infty $, then is it true that the sum of the $f_i$'s is a Radon-Nikodym derivative of the sum of the $\nu_i$'s w.r.t $\mu$?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. This is easy to see using the definitions and the monotone convergence theorem.

Simply note that

$$
\int_A \sum_i f_i d\mu = \sum_i \int_A f_i d\mu = \sum_i \nu_i(A) = (\sum_i \nu_i )(A)
$$

for each measurable $A$, where the first step is due to the monotone convergence theorem and the last step due to definition of $\sum_i \nu_i$.